# dynamically add a dropdpwn based on value inserted in autocomplete textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

Please someone help, I am really stuck on this for 2 days :|

I have a PHP form and I would like to enable user select movies by title, or by actors.
So, I was thinking about a dropdown menu by these values (moviebyTitle, moviebyActor). For selecting movies by title, I used jQuery auto-complete which get movie titles from my DB and it works fine.

This is my code:

```
<select id="selectType" name="source">
  <option value="">MoviesBy</option>
  <option value="byTitle">byTitle</option>
  <option value="byActor">byActor</option>
</select>

<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags">

<div id="byActor" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<select name="films[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px">
  <?php
   include('moviedropdown.php');
  ?>
 </select>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: "actorsauto.php",
    minLength: 2
}); 
 $("#selectType").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() == "byTitle")
        $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source", "filmsauto.php");
      else 
      if ($(this).val() == "byActor")
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
         source: "actorsauto.php",
         minLength: 2,
         select: function (event, ui){
           var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
          // Here goes your ajax call.
           $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal, q2: $("#selectType").val()}, function (response){
            // response variable above will contain the option tags. Simply put in the dropdown.
             $("#movieImdbId").html(response);
          });
      }
    });
  }
});
});                 
</script>
```

### EDIT:

and this is the actions.php: (please kindly see also javascript part above)

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']) && isset($_GET['q2']) && !empty($_GET['q2']) ){
   // Here goes the cleaning code. Never use the variables received from $_GET and $_POST directly before processing it for malicious code.
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q2 = $_GET['q2'];

//$sql = fetchResults($q, $q2); // Some function which will run a database query and return some records in either object collection or arrays etc.

//I added this part to fetch data from DB
include('imdbConnection.php');
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT movieImdbId FROM movie_roleNames WHERE castName = :q');
$sql->execute(array(':q' => $q));

$html = "";

while($row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

   $option = '<option value="' . $row->movieImdbId . '">' . $row->movieImdbId . '</option>';

$html = $option;
}
echo $html; // <-- this $html will end up receiving inside that `response` variable in the `$.post` ajax call.
exit;
}
?>
```

### My question:

I just wonder how can I add a drop down list based on the value user has typed in the textbox. For example, if user wrote "Tom Cruise" in the auto-complete textbox, a dropdown will be added that shows movies in which "Tom Cruise" has played. (I make a COMMENT in the JavaScript code where I had problem)

I really searched a lot, but all samples where to dynamically populate some dropdown ([like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/sloga/KdskX/23/), or adding a textbox based on value selected in dropdown...

Please help, I really don't mean someone write the code for me, I just want to find any sample or some way that I can learn how to do it.

Thanks,

Comment: You're using `mysql_fetch_object` to fetch the current row from the resultset. But you're accessing it as if it was an array. Either go with `$row->movieImdbId` or replace `mysql_fetch_object` to `mysql_fetch_array`.
In your javascript part, you're not using my callback function for `select` in the first condition. It's needed for both of the conditions. Otherwise the ajax call won't hit. Try adding it to both of the parts and let me know if you had any success. Also, as a helping note, you can use Browser's developer tools to see if your ajax call is even going out to the server.

Comment: You can use Firebug extension if you're using Mozilla based browser. Chrome has a builtin developer toolbar. You can access it in any browser using F10.

Comment: typo. its not F10. Its F12

Comment: @BasitNizami: Thank you for your time, I changed part related t0 mysql_fetch_object.. Please kindly see my updated code (actions.php).

Comment: @BasitNizami: about your point to javascript part, sorry but could I kindly ask you why should I use it for the first condition? (Actually, for the first condition which is "if ($(this).val() == "byTitle")", it works fine and I don't want to populate any dropdown in this case (when user select movies by titles, auto-completion is enough:p)

Comment: @BasitNizami: Sorry, one more question: In the javascript file, you wrote as a comment: "//Here goes your ajax call.", should I add some codes here?? (sorry if it is something basic, but I am really unfamiliar with ajax. )

Comment: Your `actions.php` code seems to be fine assuming `$row` in the loop contains an object collection returned from `mysql_fetch_object` from your `fetchAll()` function.
About my point to Javascript, well, the way you want to have it is when you start typing into the auto complete box, it should go to the server and then populate the drop down from the database, isn't it?. If Yes, then you will need to have an ajax call run each time user types something, which here are two scenarios. So, you need to have that `select:` section in both of those. Otherwise you can leave it if you don't want it.

Comment: about my comment in javascript. No you don't need to add anything there. `$.post` IS ajax request. Using jQuery to send an ajax request is extremely easy if you look into it and give it an hour of dedicated practice. Read more about it here. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like the following.

What you actually need is when you type into the auto complete box and select something, you need to get a hold of that value for later use. After that, you need to call the server (a php script) with an ajax call and send that value from the autocomplete box along with the value from the drop down (only if you need to). That php script will need to generate a pile of something like the following in loop and save the whole html in a variable.

`<option value='v1'>Value1</option>`
`<option value='v2'>Value2</option>`

After that, send that back to the calling ajax script and then you need to put this as the content inside that drop down that you're trying to populate.

Here's some sample code on how to accomplish the javascript part.

```
<select id="filmsdd" name="films[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px">

 </select>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: "actorsauto.php",
          minLength: 2,
          select: function (event, ui){
              var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
              // Here goes your ajax call.
              $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal, q2: $("#selectType").val()}, function (response){
                // response variable above will contain the option tags. Simply put in the dropdown.
                $("#filmsdd").html(response);
              });
          }
        });
    });
<script>
```

**EDIT:**

`path/to/somefile.php` would be any file which is stored in your directory along with other website files. let's call it `actions.php` (I have updated the $.post ajax call)

When `$.post` runs, it will send a request to `actions.php` along with two variables `q` and `q2`. These variable names can be anything.

`q` contains the selected value from the auto complete box.
`q2` contains the selected type from the drop down.

in `actions.php`, you end up with something like this.

```
if(isset($_GET['q']) && !empty($_GET['q']) && isset($_GET['q2']) && !empty($_GET['q2']) ){
   // Here goes the cleaning code. Never use the variables received from $_GET and $_POST directly before processing it for malicious code.
$q = $_GET['q'];
$q2 = $_GET['q2'];

$sql = fetchResuls($q, $q2); // Some function which will run a database query and return some records in either object collection or arrays etc.

// Initialize a variable that you will send back to your ajax call, its still waiting for this script to be completed.
$html = "";

// Assuming your function returned a list of objects. Loop through the records.
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
   $option = '<option value="' . $row->property_id . '">' . $row->property_name . '</option>';
$html .= $option;
}
echo $html; // <-- this $html will end up receiving inside that `response` variable in the `$.post` ajax call.
exit;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry but I am very new to ajax, so it was not very clear for me:| could you please tell me what is the file in path/to/somefile.php in line 11? Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I ask something that might be very simple... I also didn't understand the part about tehe PHP script with the loop that should save the html in  a variable (This line: <option value='v1'>Value1</option> <option value='v2'>Value2</option> )

Comment: No problem. I'll update my answer to also reflect some of the PHP side of the code too.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help, I am trying your answer and will update you by the result;)

Comment: I will update my post, so you could see what I had done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real question is, what's the point of the second drop down box. Why dont you just display all of the movies in a "table" once they've selected the actor.

I'd suggest a unified "Search" box, and on the PHP side, querying both your movies and actors, displaying all results that way?

If they choose a autoComplete value that is of type actor, display all the actor's movies. If they select an autoComplete value that is of type "movie" - display all the movies.

Effectivly - you're eliminating the By Actor or By Movie radio in favor of a better search bar.

Comment: @HawHogan : This is what I wanted to do, but my problem is that in case that value is of type actor, autocomplete suggest acors name.. then a new textbox or dropdown should be added dynamically in order to show the movies by that actor! and this is exactly the point that I don't know.. I mean I don't know how to add a dropdown dynamically based on the value that user typed in the textbox(autocomplete textbox)